# Retrieve data from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 Models and 1 ViewModel for now. They are listed below. I would like to display all fields from my Employee Model along with the 2 fields from my Department Model on the Index Method. So, I created the ViewModel with all the fields along with adding a `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList { get; set; }` for retrieving data to a DropDownList on my Create Method (which works fine).

**Employee Model:**

```
    public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]    
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is required")]
    public string EmpPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Start Date is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:D}")]
    public DateTime EmpStartDate { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**Department Model:**

```
    public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name is required")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string DeptName { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeViewModel:**

I would like to create just this one ViewModel for my CRUD if possible.

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }
    public string EmpPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmpStartDate { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee Controller:**

```
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private DataEntryContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(DataEntryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
    }

    // Retrieve List of Departments
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDeptList()
    {
        var dept = _context.Departments
            .Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.DeptId.ToString(),
                Text = s.DeptName
            })
            .ToList();

        return (dept);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        EmployeeViewModel selectList = new EmployeeViewModel();
        selectList.DeptList = GetDeptList();

        return View(selectList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = new Employee();

            {
                emp.EmpFirstName = employee.EmpFirstName;
                emp.EmpLastName = employee.EmpLastName;
                emp.EmpPhoneNumber = employee.EmpPhoneNumber;
                emp.EmpStartDate = employee.EmpStartDate;
                emp.DeptId = employee.DeptId;
            }

            _context.Employees.Add(emp);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

**View Index Method:**

I added the `@model IEnumerable<DataEntryMVC.Models.EmployeeViewModel>` at the top of this view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpLastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpPhoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpStartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeptName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmpId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Error Message that I receive when retrieving data:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataEntryMVC.Models.Employee], but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DataEntryMVC.Models.EmployeeViewModel]'.

Also, am I handling the Create Method properly for Adding my Data to the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `EmployeeViewModel` class( `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>`), but in your action method, you are returning the list of `Employee` entities.

The solition is to convert the entity list to view model list and return that to the view. You can do that with LINQ `Select` method.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var list=_context.Employees
                     .Select(s=> new EmployeeViewModel { 
                                                         EmpId =s.EmpId ,
                                                         EmpFirstName=s.EmpFirstName,
                                                         EmpLastName=s.EmpLastName,
                                                         EmpPhoneNumber=s.EmpPhoneNumber,
                                                         EmpStartDate=s.EmpStartDate,
                                                         DeptName=s.Department.DeptName
                                                       }).ToList();
    return View(list);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shyju, I only had to add `DeptName = s.Department.DeptName` to retrieve the DeptName value.

Can you please explain to me the difference from what I was trying to do and your example so that I can understand? I'm still learning, so please take it easy on the explanation to me :)

Comment: Read the first paragraph of the answer again. The razor view is strongly typed your view model collection, but your code was sending a list of Employee class. It is like you are filling petrol to a car with diesel engine. It will not work nicely.

Comment: So the View that I had/have is strongly typed but the original way that I was trying to retrieve the data was not and that's why I got the error that I did? 

Is this how you retrieve data from the ViewModel rather than using `return View(_context.Employee.ToList());` like I was trying to do?

Comment: Yes. The way you were doing(using a view model) is great!

Comment: I was under the impression that I would be able to retrieve the data from the ViewModel by just using this `return View(_context.Employees.ToList());` on the Index Method. Don't get me wrong, I like your method as well, but thought that I would be able to retrieve it the other way. What is the way that you used called, is there a name to what you did to get that data from the ViewModel. Just wanted to know so that I can look into that process to learn by.

Comment: It is basically reading the entities ,go through each one of them(in a loop) and creating a corresponding view model object and setting the entity object property values on the view model object propeties.  You can do that in a foeach loop, but in took advantage of LINQ select method and project to the `EmployeeViewModel` objects. There are libraries like AutoMapper which can does this mapping as well.

Comment: Would you please be able to show me how to do that using a foreach loop for my understanding. I like the way that you posted but would just like to see the other way so that I can understand how that works as well. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: So, I would just add what you supplied to the Index Method on the Controller, right? Then, what about the View itself, do I just use the same View as I originally posted? Which process do you like better and is there one process better than the other as far as performance goes?

Comment: The linq code in my answer is shorthand (and the linq way) to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for that example Shyju, I implemented it but was unable to access the DeptName field and it errored out. The DeptName is included in the ViewModel but not the main Employee Model. I'm assuming that's why but not sure how to retrieve tha

Comment: Department.DeptName

Comment: added `empVm.DeptName = e.Department.DeptName;` and get the following error message `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DataEntryMVC.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`